# What kinds of questions will the immigration officer ask?

Tags: uk-visa

In February I was refused a UK Visitor Visa because I didn't have enough money, I didn't provide enough ties to my home country (USA) and I didn't include a sponsor letter.

Now I'm going to apply for UK study visa. I know the basic questions the immigration officer will ask. But what questions will they ask in regards to the refused visa application?

Comment: For what purpose did you apply for the visitor visa? You say that your home country is the USA; are you a US citizen? Normally US citizens do not require a visitor visa for stays up to 6 months in the UK.

Comment: Yes I am a US citizen. I did research but my dad said I needed a visa for more than 90 consecutive days which he was obviously wrong. It was to spend time with my boyfriend. What kinds of questions will they ask about it?

Comment: @Kat, from your previous question on this subject, you have already subsequently been allowed into the UK as a visitor to visit your partner. That should give you some idea right there. If you are looking for exact questions they might ask in this situation, that's impossible predict. It could literally depend on the border agent's mood that day. Heck, you might even be just waived through after a brief look at your passport.

Comment: What school are you attending? How long is your course of study? Where will you be staying (you've already indicated that you will be staying your partner)? What is the source of your funding (not so important for students, but it helps to know the answer off the top of your head)? Do you plan on marrying your partner (Be firm on this, yes or no. DO NOT WAIVER ON THIS QUESTION. Whatever the answer, be decisive and explicit and, ofcourse, always tell the truth)?

Comment: As far as your previous visa refusal is concerned, they might ask about it, they might not. They have all of the details in front of them, and since your were subsequently allowed in, you were apparently truthful in all of your responses when you were refused. They have what amounts to a transcript of those questions and answers. If they want any more information than they got then, they'll ask.

Comment: @ouflak while always telling the truth is important. It is best if the truth is not that you are entering the UK with the intention of getting married since that requires a fiance visa.

Comment: @StrongBad, You aren't wrong (in fact I agree that it is not the best idea to say that). But if she is a genuine student and says that she wants to get married to her partner while studying, that shouldn't be grounds for refusal. Students are allowed to get married.

Comment: When I applied for a student visa, there weren't many questions. In fact beyond the stuff on the form (university, money) they only asked about 1 thing: I was arrested when I was 14, and they wanted to know about that. They mainly were interested in the fact that it happened 10 years in the past when I was a stupid kid ;)

As long as you have a CAS, and the CAS is from a reputable university, and you have the funds demonstrated for your tuition + the required minimum living expenses, they shouldn't care too much about the refused visit visa since it's not like you were deported.

Answer (score 2):

Immigration officers pretty much have the freedom to ask anything they feel is useful to evaluating how fit for the visa you are.

Any diligent immigration officer who notes a previous refusal - it'd certainly be within their duty to ask about it. Odds are, specifically, that they'll ask:

- the reasons for the refusal (which you've mentioned to us)
- for each of these reasons, what evidence do you have that you've remedied/documented them
- given the answers above, are you eligible.
- and then further questions about your study, where, how you'll support yourself, where you'll live and so on.